# sending props with multiple maps from parent component showing duplicate results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple blog app in react in which, I have nested json data, so every json data have a unique nested json data, I will show with every blog.

json data

```
const blogs = [
    {
         id : 1,
         title: 'First Blog',
         comments : [
            {
                commentId : 1,
                body : 'First Comment', 
            },
            {
                commentId : 3,
                body : 'First Comment', 
            },
        ]
    },
    {
         id : 2,
         title: 'Second Blog',
         comments : [
            {
                commentId : 7,
                body : 'First Comment', 
            },
            {
                commentId : 9,
                body : 'First Comment', 
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
         const blogs = this.state.blogs.map((blog) => (
           blog.comments.map((comment) => (
            <BlogDetail
              id={blog.id}
              key={blog.id}
              title={blog.title}
              commentId={comment.id}
            />
           )
         )
         return (
          <div>
            {blogs}
          </div>  
        )
    }
}

class BlogDetail extends React.Component {
    render() {
         return (
           <div>
               {this.props.id}
               {this.props.title}
           </div>
         )
    }
}
```

When I render `BlogDetail` component then it is showing one blog multiple times (depends on how many comments are on it).

I have tried many times but it is still showing this.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: what is your expected outcome from this? are you looking to show only set of blog or all the comments in the each blog?

Comment: I am trying to show comment which belongs to it.

Comment: have a look at the answer I added if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const BlogDetail = (props) => {
         return (
           <div>
               {props.commentId}
                 {' '}
               {props.commentBody}
           </div>
         )
}

function App() {
// Blogs is the json you are using
     const blogs = Blogs.map((blog) => (
         <div>
             {blog.title}
             {blog.comments.map((comment) => (
            <BlogDetail
              key={blog.id}
              commentId={comment.commentId}
              commentBody={comment.body}
            />
           )
         )}
         <br />
        </div>
        ))
  return (
    <div>
            {blogs}
          </div>  
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Using this you will get an outcome like this

```
First Blog
1 First Comment
3 First Comment

Second Blog
7 First Comment
9 First Comment
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, BlockDetail does show every comment in every post. In BlockDetail you render each comment in comments with the title, but in your json there is no such property as 'title', only the 'body'. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you see more closer, then you'll notice that body is for comment, `Title` is for blog title, I am trying to show comments on every blog which blogs to it, But it is showing multiple blogs of using `two map` functions. Is there any way to send nested json data by using one `map function` ?

Comment: With 2 map functions  you iterate over blogs (which are 2 in your mock data) and comments (2 for each blog) and in the end you got 4 BlogDetail components, right? Because it is nested, you have to use 2 loops. Or you can have another json file with only comments in it with the id of the blog post.